# How to remove an certain element in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

I've got a website which has a iFrame in it. The iFrame is linked to an external page. I want to remove some elements in the external website (the website has HTML coding) using Javascript (other methods OK too) WITHOUT anyone clicking on any "remove" buttons or do anything, so it should AUTOMATICALLY remove that element when my webpage and the iframe loads, no one can see it.
For example, I want to remove a website's logo and some contents. I've tried lots of methods but they don't work in iFrame.

Comment: If the iframed page is from a different domain, just forget about that. It's impossible to get done (cross-domain issues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot access elements in an Iframe if the Iframe is linked to an external site, there is no workaround using javascript.